# What are <selector> and <item> in android XML?

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to change the background color of my Button when it's pressed so I'm creating a drawable resource file to customise the different button states.

I'm looking at [an example xml file for this use case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22063134/6733153) and I'm trying to understand what `<item>` and `<selector>` tags are - and what they're doing.

I've tried searching but couldn't find any explanations.

Comment: You can check the Docs [State list](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource)

Answer (score 0):

`<selector>` and `<item>` are used when you are creating a custom button.

The `<selector>` tag is the root tag and it can contain multiple `<item>` tags, the only attribute it contains is the `xmlns:android`.

Example:

`<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`

`<item>` is used to define a color on different states of a component. You can find more information here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource

Comment: Thanks however I'm trying to change the background color not the text color - which is why the code snippet there is not compatable with `android:background` - I believe it needs to be nested in `<shape>` but I'm not sure where I can read more about this.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592780/selector-on-background-color-of-textview